# Javascript - socket.io get is showing not found

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, google-chrome, webrtc

I am getting error: /socket.io/1/?t=1410234556010 404 (Not Found)

```
  Socket.prototype.handshake = function (fn) {
    var self = this
      , options = this.options;

    function complete (data) {
      if (data instanceof Error) {
        self.connecting = false;
        self.onError(data.message);
      } else {
        fn.apply(null, data.split(':'));
      }
    };

    var url = [
          'http' + (options.secure ? 's' : '') + ':/'
        , options.host + ':' + options.port
        , options.resource
        , io.protocol
        , io.util.query(this.options.query, 't=' + +new Date)
      ].join('/');

    if (this.isXDomain() && !io.util.ua.hasCORS) {
      var insertAt = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
        , script = document.createElement('script');

      script.src = url + '&jsonp=' + io.j.length;
      insertAt.parentNode.insertBefore(script, insertAt);

      io.j.push(function (data) {
        complete(data);
        script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
      });
    } else {
      var xhr = io.util.request();

      xhr.open('GET', url, true);
      if (this.isXDomain()) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
      }
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          xhr.onreadystatechange = empty;

          if (xhr.status == 200) {
            complete(xhr.responseText);
          } else if (xhr.status == 403) {
            self.onError(xhr.responseText);
          } else {
            self.connecting = false;            
            !self.reconnecting && self.onError(xhr.responseText);
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.send(null);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add socket.io.js to your client.

FOR HTML:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

FOR JADE:

`script(type='text/javascript',src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')`